# How to separate created group sprites into individual sprites

Tags: javascript, sprite

I'm trying to create a small game that has a soldier moving around a small area and fires bullets. I'm a new programmer who just started javascript not but a few months ago, and so I apologize if my question is poorly worded or my code is clunky.

I've tried using [group].get(i) to isolate each individual sprite that comes out of the gun, but it simply breaks and crashes the program.

Here is all of the code for my (small) program:

```
var soldier = createSprite(200, 200);
soldier.setAnimation("soldier_still");
var bullet = createGroup();
function draw() {
  background(rgb(100, 85, 45));
  move();
  attack();
  drawSprites();
}
function attack() {
  if (mouseWentDown("leftButton")) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      bullet.add(createSprite(soldier.x, soldier.y));
      bullet.setAnimationEach("bullet");
      bullet.pointToEach(World.mouseX, World.mouseY);
      bullet.setLifetimeEach(50);
      bullet.setSpeedAndDirectionEach(20, World.mouseX, World.mouseY);
    }
  }
}
function move() {
  createEdgeSprites();
  World.allSprites.bounceOff(topEdge);
  World.allSprites.bounceOff(bottomEdge);
  World.allSprites.bounceOff(leftEdge);
  World.allSprites.bounceOff(rightEdge);
  soldier.pointTo (World.mouseX,World.mouseY);
  if (keyDown() == false) {
    soldier.setAnimation("soldier_still");
    soldier.velocityX = 0;
    soldier.velocityY = 0;
  }
  if (keyDown("up")) {
    soldier.setAnimation("soldier_move");
    soldier.velocityY = -5;
  }
  if (keyDown("down")) {
    soldier.setAnimation("soldier_move");
    soldier.velocityY = 5;
  }
  if (keyDown("left")) {
    soldier.setAnimation("soldier_move");
    soldier.velocityX = -5;
  }
  if (keyDown("right")) {
    soldier.setAnimation("soldier_move");
    soldier.velocityX = 5;
  }
}
```

The program either crashes, or all bullet sprites face the mouse's position. Is there anyway I can improve my code, or a solution to making each group (bullet) sprite its own individual sprite?

Comment: It looks like you're using a library (sprites aren't built into JS); what library are you using? It'll be easier for people to help if we know.